# How to tf.loadLayersModel of mobilenet v2

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

```
tf.loadLayersModel('https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/tfjs/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224/model.json');
```

works fine but I would like to load v2 instead. I tried

```
tf.loadLayersModel('https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/savedmodel/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224/model.json')
```

but I get an error about improper layer format.

In general how is one supposed to find pre-converted pre-trained TFJS models?

Answer (score 1):

The v2 model found at the url specified is not a tfjs format thus throwing the error. You would need to use the tfjs-converter to convert the savedmodel to a tfjs format.

tfjs does host the v2 format on tfhub. All models available for downloading can be found [here](https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet)

```js
(async() => {

const modelUrl =
   'https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_140_224/classification/2';
const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(modelUrl, {fromTFHub: true})
const zeros = tf.zeros([1, 224, 224, 3]);
model.predict(zeros).print();

})()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
```